# Efficiently removing the first element of every array inside an arraylist in Java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, out-of-memory

I want to remove the first element from every `double[][]` array that is stored inside of an `ArrayList<double[][]>`. This list stores a great amount of data (60000 elements).

I tried to achieve this with the following code:

```
public ArrayList<double[][]> correctInput(ArrayList<double[][]> input) {
    double[][] temp;
    ArrayList<double[][]> correctedinput = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int n = 0; n < input.size(); n++) {
        temp = new double[input.get(0).length - 1][1];

        for (int i = input.get(n).length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            temp[i - 1][0] = input.get(n)[i][0];
        }

        correctedinput.add(temp);
    }

    return correctedinput;
}
```

While my code works for smaller list, when trying to use it on the big list it results in an

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC Overhead Limit Exceeded

Probably because I am redefining the double array (named temp) for every element of the list.
One more thing: the Arrays inside of the list are used as vectors, which is why they are 2D arrays although the only they are only of the length 1.

'temp[0].lenght = 1'

The question is how I would make this run more efficiently for very big lists.
Any kind of hint would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you really need to leave the original ArrayList unchanged after creating the new ArrayList? Maybe there's just not enough room for both ArrayLists to exist together.

Comment: That could be. The ArrayList doesn't need to stay unchanged.

Comment: Could you provide some proper input?

Comment: That's a bit problematic since it has to work on the ArrayList of the size 60000, but the following would result in an Array that is very similar (although smaller) to the 60000 one.   'for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  A.add(new double[][] { { Math.random() * 10 }, { Math.random() * 10 }, { Math.random() * 10 } }); '

Comment: Is it important to preserve the input?  Is random access into the input important?  If not, consider using either LinkedList or Deque or similar as they are optimized for removal of head/tail in O(1).  It will also avoid the case where you have to create another large array for your result.

Comment: Why are you using a 2D array, but the second dimension is always 1? Can't you just use a simple 1D array instead?

Comment: The OP says one thing but then the code he claims is working has a different output than the expected.

Comment: @dbl how is it different?

Comment: @AlexC random access is not important, so I could try something like a linkedlist. But I am not sure what you mean by if it is important to preserve input. input may be deleted or altered as long as the contents of it are returned (expect the first element of every array of course).

Comment: @dbl where does my code claim different things than I do in my question? if it does i would like to correct myself

Comment: @DodgyCodeException I'm using such a 2D Array since I ran into the same problems while i tried to convert a 1D array into such an 2D array. I need this kindo of array because its an vector input for an Perceptron

Comment: @Z3R0 my bad, the input I've used was the wrong one.

Comment: this one leads to ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException :) res.add(new double[][] {{0.1, 0.11}, {0.2, 0.22}, {0.3, 0.33}, {0.4, 0.44}});
res.add(new double[][] {{1.0, 11.0}, {2.0, 22.0}, {3.0, 33.0}, {4.0, 44.0}});

Comment: Yes that's right, I intend to use this on Arrays of the length "Arr[0].length = 1" only. I should have specified that. Will try to correct it in my initial question.

Comment: @Z3R0 I was wondering if you could just modify the 'input' or if you actually needed to make a modification/copy to return and preserve input.  If you wan't and can modify the 'input' passed in, I would use LinkedList or Deque, no allocation and O(1) removal.

Comment: I do not need to preserve "input" and will look into this further, as well

Comment: @Z3R0 check my answer. It doesn't require much more memory than you've already used to initialize the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this method:

**Java 8+**

```
public static <T> void remove1stArrayElementFromEveryElement(List<T[]> list) {
    list.replaceAll(array -> Arrays.copyOfRange(array, 1, array.length));
}
```

**Java 7+**

```
public static <T> void remove1stArrayElementFromEveryElement(List<T[]> list) {
    for (ListIterator<T[]> iter = list.listIterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
        T[] array = iter.next();
        array = Arrays.copyOfRange(array, 1, array.length);
        iter.set(array);
    }
}
```

I've made it generic, so that it works equally well with `double[][]` or `int[][]`. It's a void method because it directly modifies the passed list, without making a copy. The only copy it makes is a temporary one of each array that's in the list. Also, it works with any list, not just `ArrayList`.

Comment: While this looks perfect I'm unable to get it to work since Eclipse tells me that it is not applicable to "ArrayList<double[][]>". Sorry, I am very inexperienced with generic method's.

Comment: @Z3R0 that's strange, it works ok when I pass it an `ArrayList<double[][]>`. Can you give me the exact error message? What about if you just call `list.replaceAll` (as in my snippet above) directly without wrapping it inside this method?

Comment: Yes! that worked perfectly. Thank you seems I have to learn way lambda expressions

Answer (score 1):

The size of arrays in Java cannot be changed. So, you cannot technically remove an element from an array. You basically need to construct a new array and then copy from the original. This is exactly what you did.

For copying, `Arrays.copyOfRange(oldArr, 1, oldArr.length)` maybe the easiest way. Try it to see there is any change.

I think you have some other options here:

1. Increase Heap (with -Xmx1024m for example)
2. Reconsider you double[][] input? Is there any work around?

Comment: I could use int[][] as input, but i'm not sure if that would help.

Comment: Yes, it's better. int eats less memory than double.

Comment: I have to correct myself while it would be possible to use int[][] it would mean that i would later have to translate it from int[][] to double[][] or I have to change nearly all of my project classes, which means that i would rather like to not do that.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't need to preserve the input list and since you have enough memory for it, this one should work just fine for you. Instead of creating a new object, simply alter the current one. For each of the outer arrays create a copy of it by skipping the first element then set the new one.

```
public static void correctInputVoid(ArrayList<double[][]> input) {
    for (ListIterator<double[][]> listIterator = input.listIterator(); listIterator.hasNext(); ) {
        double[][] next = listIterator.next();
        listIterator.set(Arrays.copyOfRange(next, 1, next.length));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be no solution for your problem, other than running the program on a machine with more RAM (if you already gave the JVM everything you have).

Your program will allocate x bytes of heap for the input and then nearly another x for the corrected list. The `OutOfMemoryError` tells you, that the JVM couldn't allocate more memory and that includes trying to free memory allocated by unused references (GC work).

> [OutOfMemoryError](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html) Java8 SE
>
> Thrown when the Java Virtual Machine cannot allocate an object because it is out of memory, and no more memory could be made available by the garbage collector.

The thing is, there are no unused references in your program as you store them in the output list. That means, the machine running this code must have sizeOfInput*2 bytes RAM to not run into the `OutOfMemoryError`

On a side note:
Seeing that you don't need a 2nd dimension, as all your array initializers use `1` for the 2nd dimension, use one dimensional arrays instead. This alone will give a huge perfomance boost.

Comment: Okay, i fear that i might run into the same error again while trying to translate from the proposed 1D array to a 2D array later, but I will try that since i don't have any ram left to allocate.

Comment: If ouy are not required to process everything in one go, do it sequentially. Read some input until you reach a cap (e.g. specified by command line parameter), process it, output it (maybe to a file on disk?) then repeat until done.